# Multiple files in htaccess files tag

Tags: .htaccess

How I add multiple files in htaccess files tag? The code bellow works for one file.

```
<Files wp-login.php>
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from 191.211.9.1
Deny from all
</Files>
```

I end up using this:

```
<filesMatch "^(wp-login|wp-file)\.php$">
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from 190.190.0.1
Deny from all
</filesMatch>
```

Comment: Use `FilesMatch` instead: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#filesmatch

Comment: Thanks. That took me the right direction.

Answer (score 14):

Try something like this(*not tested but should work*):

```
<Files ~ "^(admin|wp-login|one-more-file)\.php$">
```

or this:

```
<FilesMatch "^(admin|wp-login|one-more-file)\.php$">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was a starting point that solved my problem

Comment: @Alqin, could you share your solution in either comments or as an answer?

Comment: This worked for me    
    <Files ~ (filename1|filename2)\.pdf>
    Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
    </Files>

Comment: Just to note, on some shared hostings, lower hosting tier may not have FilesMatch enabled and then it's necessary to use Files

Answer (score 2):

## 2023 Solution

Here are some options to do so:

#### Returning `"Forbidden"` to the user:

In this case, "user"/"hacker"/"adversary"/"pentester" would figure out those files exist on your server but s/he doesn't have access to them!

```
<FilesMatch "(?:readme|license|changelog|-config|-sample)\.(?:php|md|txt|html?)">
      Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

#### Returning `"404"` to the user:

In this case, "user"/"hacker"/"adversary"/"pentester", theoretically, would assume those files don't even exist on your server!

```
<FilesMatch "(?:readme|license|changelog|-config|-sample)\.(?:php|md|txt|html?)">
      Redirect 404
</FilesMatch>
```